# Add custom metadata when sending an email using mandrill and receive metadata in an inbound event

Tags: email, mandrill, email-headers

i will like to know if there is a way to **add custom metadata when sending an email using the mandrill API (/messages/send.json) and receive this metadata in an inbound event**. I know that there is a way as it's explained here https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582417-Using-Custom-Message-Metadata; but i am afraid this metadata will not be included in [inbound emails](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583207-What-is-the-format-of-inbound-email-webhooks-), only in [message events](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583307-Message-Event-Webhook-format)

Is it possible to receive custom metadata (or custom fields) in inbound emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also mislead this things first time I read docs about Mandrill events ^_^ **Message Events** represent actual inbound mails. Mandrill receives SMTP mail and sends HTTP request with JSON representation (+ additional info from service) of such event (type: inbound) to yours webhook.
**Inbound Events** represent events that occurred with outbound mails. Mandrill sends HTTP request with JSON representation (+ additional info from service) of such event (type: sent, bounced, rejected, etc) to yours webhook.

No, it's not possible to send metadata with **inbound event** as far you **only receive** such events. You may only receive metadata back in **message event**.

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582417-Using-Custom-Message-Metadata

> Mandrill allows you to attach custom, individualized metadata to
>   messages. Use custom metadata to integrate your application's data
>   model with Mandrill. Metadata is searchable (either in the activity
>   view or via the API) and is included with webhook events and activity
>   CSV exports.

But if you want to get back some info in reply to your outbound mail, you may pass some custom header, e.g. `X-My-Own-Metadata: 42`, and expect all intermediates (including Mandrill) will not cut it during transmission.